# How to run gitlab yaml project configuration from terminal?

Tags: terminal, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci

I´m trying to run a [gitlab pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html) from command line. I am learning configuring various options provided by gitlab https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

I know I can just specify the branch name and then pushing to the repository. Then, when I push, gitlab executes the jobs defined in the yaml file, but:

> How can I simulate the gitlab-ci.yaml file function so I do not have
>   to push to test it? Is it possible to run a terminal/console command to run the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

> You can do it by posting to a [gitlab trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)

As they say, you can do it with minimal effort:

First, create the Trigger in **Settings ➔ CI/CD under Triggers. Add trigger**

Second, call your trigger with [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

```
curl --request POST \
 --form token=TOKEN \
 --form ref=master \
 https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the **top right** of the image taken from the [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html#seeing-pipeline-status), you can run a pipeline (`Run Pipeline` button) for a specific branch via a button (without pushing):

[image]

Comment: thats not what I am asking, I have clearly mentioned how can I run the gitlab.yaml config from terminal (shell)

Comment: Oke; You can't. This is the only option. Or use the API to trigger my suggested option above.